# Preventing dividing by zero in list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, divide-by-zero

I have the following code:

```
scores = [matrix[i][i] / sum(matrix[i]) for (i, scores) in enumerate(matrix)]
```

My problem is that `sum(matrix[i])` could be 0 in some cases, resulting in a `ZeroDivisionError`. But because `matrix[i][i]` is also 0 in that case, I solved this as follows:

```
scores = [divide(matrix[i][i], sum(matrix[i])) for (i, scores) in enumerate(matrix)]
```

The function `divide(x, y)` returns 1 if `y == 0` and `(x / y)` if `y > 0`. But I wonder if there is an easier way. Maybe I could use some ternary operator, but does that exist in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in Python it's called the [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
[matrix[i][i] / sum(matrix[i]) if sum(matrix[i]) != 0 else 0 
 for (i, scores) in enumerate(matrix)]
```

Comment: But this will make `sum` calculated twice.

Comment: @ovgolovin Sadly yes, but it's a solution nonetheless :3

Comment: Yeah, no doubt this is a solution. +1 for that. I just wonder if it is possible to reuse the result of `sum` inside list comprehension.

Comment: So, the proposed solution is faster?

Comment: @Lewistrick Depends on how you implement `divide`. If it calculates `sum` twice, it is no faster.

Comment: @ovgolovin No, that doesn't depend on the implementation of `divide`, because it calculates `sum` before `divide`.

Comment: @Lewistrick Then your solution is presumably faster as `sum` is calculated once, and here it is calculated twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
[(lambda x, y: 0 if y == 0 else x/y)(row[i], sum(row))
 for i, row in enumerate(matrix)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary conditionals do exist:

```
'blah' if True else 'wee'
```